# Javascript onload isn't working for my random word generator

Tags: javascript

onload in js isn't working for me. I'm trying to get it to randomly generate a movie for a hangman game, however, it's not wanting to load. I've tried running it in CodePen as well, so it's nothing to do with the links. Any suggestions would be great.

```js
var movieTitles = [
  "halloween",
  "suspiria",
  "audition",
  "hereditary",
  "the beyond",
  "the evil dead",
  "the blair witch project"
];

// Execute on page load.
document.getElementById("movie-title").onload = function() {updateMovieToGuess();};


//Generating random horror movie title

var updateMovieToGuess = function() {
  movieToGuess = movieTitles[Math.floor(Math.random() * movieTitles.length)];

};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Hangman</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script scr="javascript/games.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IM+Fell+Double+Pica+SC" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <p id='any-key'>Press any key to get started</p>
    <p id='movie-title'>Movie Title:</p>
    <p id='letters'>Letters Guessed:</p>
    <p id='lives-left'>Lives Remaining:</p>
    <p id='wins'>Movies You've Survived: </p>
    <p id='lost'>Movies You Died In:</p>
    
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should use `window.onload` and bind your function to it.

Comment: Check the code in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get a variable to be stored in `movieToGuess`

```js
var movieTitles = [
  "halloween",
  "suspiria",
  "audition",
  "hereditary",
  "the beyond",
  "the evil dead",
  "the blair witch project"
];

// Execute on page load.
window.onload = function() {updateMovieToGuess();};


//Generating random horror movie title

var updateMovieToGuess = function() {
  movieToGuess = movieTitles[Math.floor(Math.random() * movieTitles.length)];
 console.log(movieToGuess);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Hangman</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script scr="javascript/games.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IM+Fell+Double+Pica+SC" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <p id='any-key'>Press any key to get started</p>
    <p id='movie-title'>Movie Title:</p>
    <p id='letters'>Letters Guessed:</p>
    <p id='lives-left'>Lives Remaining:</p>
    <p id='wins'>Movies You've Survived: </p>
    <p id='lost'>Movies You Died In:</p>

    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, what I usually do for random things is this.

```
var rand = Math.random(0, 100)

if (rand < 'put percentage here') {
print('then do which one you want')
}
```

That maybe could work, and also do that for each one.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DOMContentLoaded` for `document` instead of `onload` for `p`.

`onload` is used for such elements as `script`, `link`, `img`, etc. - for those, that are loading data. `p` does not load any data, so `onload` won't be fired.

`DOMContentLoaded` event is being fired when `DOM` is ready to use, so it's your choice! :)

```js
var movieTitles = [
  "halloween",
  "suspiria",
  "audition",
  "hereditary",
  "the beyond",
  "the evil dead",
  "the blair witch project"
];


//Generating random horror movie title
function updateMovieToGuess() {
  movieToGuess = movieTitles[Math.floor(Math.random() * movieTitles.length)];
  console.log(movieToGuess) 
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", updateMovieToGuess)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Hangman</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <!-- <script scr="javascript/games.js"></script> -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IM+Fell+Double+Pica+SC" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <p id='any-key'>Press any key to get started</p>
    <p id='movie-title'>Movie Title:</p>
    <p id='letters'>Letters Guessed:</p>
    <p id='lives-left'>Lives Remaining:</p>
    <p id='wins'>Movies You've Survived: </p>
    <p id='lost'>Movies You Died In:</p>

    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to trigger the `onload` event on `#movie-title` instead of the whole page, here is the error.

Just do:

```
window.onload = function() {updateMovieToGuess();};
```